# how to set custom rule for unused variable and method in php code sinffer?

Tags: php, symfony-3.1, phpcs

I am using php code sniffer with smyfony 3.1.

**Package Name:Squiz**
I am trying to run phpcs command in my symfony based project.

**Command:**

```
phpcs --standard=/c/xampp/php/pear/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Squiz  src/MYBundle/Controller/MYController.php
```

Command is working fine, In this controller/class i have declared some private variable and method name which is not used anywhere in the controller/class.

**Ruleset**

I have appended new  rule in the ruleset.xml file and create new file under this directory **[Sniffs\Rule\UnusedPrivateField]** `UnusedPrivateField.php`

```
<rule name="UnusedPrivateField"
          since="0.2"
          message="Avoid unused private fields such as '{0}'."
          class="Sniffs\Rule\UnusedPrivateField"
          externalInfoUrl="http://phpmd.org/rules/unusedcode.html#unusedprivatefield"></rule>
```

**Question:**
How to call "UnusedPrivateField.php" code from new rule set ?

Comment: The format of your rule tag looks unlike any PHPCS example one, so I'm not sure why you've written it like that. Is there a particular reason? Also, you don't actually need to include rule tags for sniff that exist under the `Sniffs` folder of a standard - PHPCS will import them automatically (use `phpcs -vv` to see how the ruleset is parsed). But you don't say under which `Sniffs` folder you put the sniff - is it under `Squiz/Sniffs`? You also seem to say you've got a 3-folder structure when PHPCS expects two (`Sniffs/CategoryName/SniffName.php`). I think I need more information to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UnusedPrivateElementsSniff](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard#slevomatcodingstandardclassesunusedprivateelements-1) for this.

I use it for over a year and it works great.